# Assembly under Mac OS X: Find files in a directory / read content of a directory using syscalls

Tags: macos, file, assembly, directory, bsd

How can I read the content of a directory in assembly under Mac OS X using syscalls? I tried opening the directory with the following:

```
;;  Open the current working directory for reading
;;  
push dword 0        ; O_RDONLY (Mode = 0) as directory already exists
push dword 0        ; flags
push dword testdir  ; Defined in .data as: testdir db "test", 0
mov eax, 0x05       ; Open system call
sub esp, 4          ; OS X (and BSD) system calls need extra space on stack 
int 0x80
jc exit_error_after_call_16
add esp, byte 16    ; 3 args * 4 bytes/arg + 4 bytes extra space = 16 bytes
```

I then tried to access the content of the directory reading the file content (all directories are files as well?) into a buffer.

```
push dword MAXFNAMELEN  ; input length
push dword tempFName    ; buffer
push dword eax          ; file descriptor value
mov eax, 0x03           ; Execute read system call
sub esp, 4
int 0x80
add esp, byte 16

; Check if file could be read without error or EOF
jc exit_error           ; CF set = error --> exit
test eax, eax       
jz exit_noerror     ; If EAX is 0 then EOF reached (stack breakdown at exit)
```

Then I tried printing the buffer for debugging, but don't get content:

```
push dword eax          ; The length of the buffer to print
push dword tempFName    ; The buffer to print
push dword 1            ; File descriptor value
mov eax, 0x04
sub esp, 4
int 0x80
add esp, byte 16
```

Any idea? Also, in good old DOS times there were two DOS functions FindFirst (0x4E) and FindNext. Is there any equivalent in syscalls?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: See [the list of syscalls](http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master) in Darwin. I believe `getdirentries` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also be aware that these code samples have little relevance to system / kernel calls on a  modern x86-64 OS, with the application running in user space.

Comment: @BrettHale Could you please explain? I know that one shouldn't use syscalls on Mac OS X as Apple reserves the right to change them anytime. However, for a specific version using them works well even for user space applicaitons. What am I missing? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @SamiLaine Thanks, I think you are right. I will try to code a sample and post the result.